# Child of the parent acting like him

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

today I have a question that is bothering me for some hours. I have watched a tutorial about magnetic field on youtube I implimeented it and I have got a problem. In that implementation I had to make an object that will be attracted and another that will attract. The one that is attracted I had to create an empty game object and give it a collider where was written is trigger. Now the problem is that I have a health script so when the player touches any object with his body he loses health. This sphere collider is part of the player and whenever it touches a body the player looses health.  I need help with this because the sphere collider has a pretty big radius and whenever it touches he gameobjects the player looses health. I need the sphere collider when it touches the gameobject to not loose health from the player please help!

```
void Start ()
    {
        cur_Health = max_Health;
        cur_Fuel = max_Fuel;
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        StartP.SetActive (true);
        score = 0;
        UpdateScore ();
        FinishP.SetActive (false);
        LoseP.SetActive (false);
        /*StartCoroutine (SpawnWaves ());
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore") != null)
        {
            highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("HighScore");
        }*/
    }
    public void PlayButton()
    {
        Start ();
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        StartP.SetActive (false);
    }
    public void NextButton()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel (1);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.R))
        {
            Application.LoadLevel (0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Q))
        {
            Application.LoadLevel (1);
        }
        cur_Fuel -= 0.04f;
        float calc_Fuel = cur_Fuel / max_Fuel;
        SetFuelBar (calc_Fuel);
        if(score >= checkpoint && cur_Health >= H && cur_Fuel >= F)
        {
            FinishP.SetActive (true);
        }
        else if(score >= checkpoint && cur_Health <= H && cur_Fuel <= F )
        {
            LoseP.SetActive (true);
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
        }
        if(cur_Fuel <= 0f)
        {
            death += 1;
            if (death == 1) 
            {
                heart.enabled = false;
                FuelBar.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1,1,1);
                cur_Fuel = 100f;
            }
            else if (death == 2) 
            {
                heart1.enabled = false;
                FuelBar.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1,1,1);
                cur_Fuel = 100f;
            }
            else if(death == 3)
            {
                FuelBar.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (0,1,1);
                camera.transform.parent = null;
                Instantiate (playerExplosion,transform.position, transform.rotation);
                heart2.enabled = false;
                LoseP.SetActive (true);
            }
        }
        if(cur_Fuel >= 100f)
        {
            FuelBar.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1,1,1);
            cur_Fuel = 100f;
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Magnet")
        {
            cur_Health -= 1f;
            float calc_Health = cur_Health / max_Health;
            SetBar (calc_Health);
        }
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Barrir")
        {
            cur_Health -= 60f;
            float calc_Health = cur_Health / max_Health;
            SetBar (calc_Health);
        }
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Fuel")
        {
            cur_Fuel += 20f;
            float calc_Fuel = cur_Fuel / max_Fuel;
            SetFuelBar (calc_Fuel);
            Destroy (col.gameObject);
        }
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" || col.gameObject.tag == "Asteroid2" || col.gameObject.tag == "Asteroid3")
        {
            cur_Health -= 30f;
            float calc_Health = cur_Health / max_Health;
            SetBar (calc_Health);
        }
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Black")
        {
            cur_Health -= 45f;
            float calc_Health = cur_Health / max_Health;
            SetBar (calc_Health);
        }
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Black1") 
        {
            if(heart.enabled == true && heart1.enabled == true && heart2.enabled == true)
            {
                heart.enabled = false;
                Bar.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1,1,1);
                cur_Health = 100f;
            }
            else if(heart1.enabled == true && heart2.enabled == true)
            {
                heart1.enabled = false;
                Bar.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1,1,1);
                cur_Health = 100f;
            }
            else if(heart2.enabled == true)
            {
                heart2.enabled = false;
                Bar.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (0,1,1);
                camera.transform.parent = null;
                Instantiate (playerExplosion,col.transform.position, col.transform.rotation);
                LoseP.SetActive (true);
            }
        }
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Health")
        {
            cur_Health += 15f;
            float calc_Health = cur_Health / max_Health;
            SetBar (calc_Health);
            Destroy (col.gameObject);
        }
        if(cur_Health <= 0f)
        {
            death += 1;
            if (death == 1) 
            {
                heart.enabled = false;
                Bar.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1,1,1);
                cur_Health = 100f;
            }
            else if (death == 2) 
            {
                heart1.enabled = false;
                Bar.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1,1,1);
                cur_Health = 100f;
            }
            else if(death == 3)
            {
            Bar.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (0,1,1);
                camera.transform.parent = null;
            Instantiate (playerExplosion,col.transform.position, col.transform.rotation);
                heart2.enabled = false;
                LoseP.SetActive (true);
            }
        }
        if(cur_Health >= 100f)
        {
            Bar.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1,1,1);
            cur_Health = 100f;
        }
    }
    void SetBar(float myhealth)
    {
        Bar.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (myhealth,Bar.transform.localScale.y,Bar.transform.localScale.z);
    }
    void SetFuelBar(float myFuel)
    {
        FuelBar.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (myFuel,FuelBar.transform.localScale.y,FuelBar.transform.localScale.z);
    }
    public void AddScore (int newScoreValue)
    {
        score += newScoreValue;
        UpdateScore ();
    }
```

Comment: share  your health script so I can see what's going on

Comment: Your question is impossible to parse.  Voting to close.

Comment: hi everyone ok I will show you my health script

Comment: here check it it si the biggest part, my health script is also a hgamecontroller kind of script

Comment: I am using it on the player

Comment: so can somebody help me?

Comment: Adding a few line breaks possibly would have made your question readable..

Comment: ok I will count this next time, thanks for your help very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this seems pretty much messed up situation here. First of all I would advice you to read answers from [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/810312/get-ontriggerenter-of-a-child.html) and [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/410711/trigger-in-child-object-calls-ontriggerenter-in-pa.html) to get an Idea of whats happening in your game.

Now lets try to solve the issue based on what information you have shared in your question. I assume that the magnet object (which get attracted due to big sphere) has tag "magnet" so the following code in your `OnTriggerEnter()` method is decreasing health when your sphere collider collides with it:

```
if(col.gameObject.tag == "Magnet")
{
    cur_Health -= 1f;
    float calc_Health = cur_Health / max_Health;
    SetBar (calc_Health);
}
```

If you don't want to decrease your health when you pick up magnet objects, remove this code.

Now coming to this part of your question:

> Now the problem is that I have a health script so when the player
>   touches any object with his body he loses health

Triggers are caused by all child colliders when rigidbody is attached to parent object. So to solve this issue:

1. Add a new layer from [Tags and Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TagManager.html) and name it "Magnet".
2. Now go to [Physics Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html) and configure Layer Collision Matrix to set magnet layer only collidable to itself like this:

[image]

3. now set this layer to both sphere object (child object of player) and the magnet object which triggers the magnetic affect.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: hey thanks for helping very much, other people jus said whats wrong but you helped thanks, I will try to do that and  will tell if it works, thanks, the magnet should take of health it is not a problem, the problem is that when the child collides with other object player looses health , well you answered thanks I will try and then tell you if it works.

Comment: oh my god, you fixed everything, thank you very much, I never knew about layers it is perfect, works perfectly thank you very much, wish you good luck in all the thingfs you will want realize, thanks a lot !